# javascript validate @ sign in text area

Tags: javascript

Im trying to do an assignment and having trouble getting code to validate. Problem is I need the email text box in form to check if "@" is present, but also in same form I need to check if name text box is empty or not. I can only get one of them to work at once.

This is my coding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Weclome to the Recipe Collection Website</title>
    <script>
    function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
     {
     alert("Name text box must be filled out");
     return false;
     }
    </script>
    <script>
    function checkEmail()
    {
    var y=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos=y.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=y.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=y.length)
     {
     alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
     return false;
     }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Number of recipes previously submitted: <input type="radio" name="recipes" value="0">0<br>
        <input type="radio" name="recipes" value="1-2">1-2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="recipes" value="3-4">3-4<br>
        <input type="radio" name="recipes" value="5+">5+<br>
        Have you ever submitted recipes to another site?: <input type="radio" name="othersite" value="yes">Yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="othersite" value="no" checked>No<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this way off?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

#### Working [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/cLEcZ/)

The root cause of your problem is that you are returning a falsey value from your validation methods even when everything is okay.

#### First the easy part is combining the two methods:

I would not do inline js, but sticking with what you have... just create a method that combines both functions:

```
<script>
function doBoth() {
    return validateForm() && checkEmail();
}
<script>

...

<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return doBoth()" method="post">
```

#### Second is fixing the short circuiting issue

However, there is an error with your two methods, you are implicitly returning `undefined` from them. `undefined` is falsey, so `doBoth` will never get to the second method. This is because of [short circuiting](http://www.openjs.com/articles/syntax/short_circuit_operators.php). JS is lazy so if the first part of an `&&` statement is false, JS stops and doesn't evaluate the second part, since there is now no way the whole statement can be true.

The solution to this problem is to return `true` if things are validated okay.

Also, note that you are missing a closing bracket in `validateForm`

```
<script>

function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        alert("Name text box must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    // everything ok *this is a MUST to return*
    return true;
}

function checkEmail()
{
    var y=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos=y.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=y.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=y.length)
    {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }

    // everything ok *this is a MUST to return*
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: So this looks much cleaner, but I still cant get it to validate. Am i just to enter one function after the other?

Comment: @RyanW - the problem is you need to add a "return true" if everythying is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I know where you've picked this up from, try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="") {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
}

var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to use code above, but still couldnt get it to work. I must be doing something way off